# How can we figure out what fraction of pure states in a Hilbert space are entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

The full Hilbert space of a quantum system will generally contain entangled states, and thus when entanglement is lost through decoherence, parts of Hilbert space become inaccessible. Is there a simple way to quantify how many pure states become inaccessible when all entanglement is lost? In other words, what fraction of pure states in a Hilbert space are entangled?

A concrete example is the two-qubit system spanned by the product states $\{|00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle,|11\rangle\}$. This space contains entangled states, e.g. the Bell state $(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, so the fraction of entangled states is greater than zero. But ignoring entangled states does not simply correspond to projecting the 4-dimensional Hilbert space onto something of lower dimension, as the product state basis still spans a 4D space.

So is there some way to quantify, or at least estimate, how much of Hilbert space contains entangled states?

Note that my question does not simply ask for an argument as to whether there are more entangled than un-entangled states, rather it is about how those two amounts can be quantified and compared.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there more entangled states or non-entangled ones?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268831/)

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks, that is for sure relevant for this discussion, though I wouldn't say that the answers there quite qualify as answers for my question in the way that the answers below do.

Comment: I'm no expert. I'm just guessing. The number of states/coefficients for a d dimensional space is $\mathbb{C}^d$. $d-1$ after normalization. For N particles who each has n basis, the number of product state is $\mathbb{C}^{(n-1)N}$ and the number of unconstrained states is $\mathbb{C}^{n^N-1}$. The minus one comes from normalization. Just like a plane is measure zero in higher dimensional space. I guess the product states is measure zero in the unconstrained Hilbert space

Comment: Do you consider only pure states or also mixed entangled states?

Comment: Only pure states, I have edited the question

Comment: The fraction is one, as explained in several of the answers to the question that Tobias Fünke linked. I've tried to explain why in my own answer, but someone didn't like it lol. Anyway, I see this as a duplicate question.

Comment: For a system of more than one qubit, the set of product states is Zariski-open in the full state space.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been Zariski-**closed** of course.

Answer (score 0):

(Almost) All the states in a Hilbert space are entangled. To see this, we consider the reduced density matrix of a given state (obtained by tracing out a subsystem), $\rho$. The state is pure iff.
$$
\text{Tr} [- \rho \ln \rho] = - \sum_i \lambda_i \ln \lambda_i  = 0 . 
$$
where $\lambda_i \in [0,1]$ and $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$ are eigenvalues of $\rho$. The only way that the equation above can be true is if any one of the eigenvalues is 1 and the rest are zero.
In every other case, the state is entangled.

Comment: It is a bit more than what you seemto be implying here. Any state with the spectrum $1,0,0...$ will be pure. This means any unitarily equivalent state will be pure, which is still a set of measure 0, but a lot more than simply $n$ states

Comment: Agreed and fixed.

Comment: I guess this is assuming that there is a subsystem to trace out, since trivially the single-qubit Hilbert space has no entangled states?

Comment: @BySymmetry Why this set has measure zero (following from this argument - and which measure of course)? You can parameterize the unitary operators by continuous parameters which should give an uncountable number of pure states. (compare to the Bloch sphere, for example).

Comment: @Codename47 - Entanglement is a quantity that captures how two subsystems of a quantum system are correlated to each other. Subsystem is a pre-requisite needed to define entanglement.

Comment: @Prahar Yep, just wanted to make sure I understood your answer in full. Indeed, the presence of subsystems is not strictly enough to allow entanglement, since the single qubit Hilbert space is equivalent to that spanned by $\{|00\rangle,|01\rangle\}$. This is of course a very pedantic comment, but I just wanted all assumptions to be made explicit.

Comment: Do we have any guarantees that density matrices exist with non-unit eigenvalues exist? Or a measure of how many of them there are?

Comment: @Codename47 - Density matrix can be whatever you want, as long as its trace is 1.